# Arrange odd numbers first, followed by even number. order of odd even should not be changed

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, big-o

Below is code snippet to reorder odd numbers followed by even numbers without changing the order of even/odd numbers in original array.

input  - {1, 4, 8, 3, 9, 12, 7}
output - {1, 3, 9, 7, 4, 8, 12}

Can We improve this from O(n2) in space (without using extra space)?

```
public  static void reOrder(int[] arr) {
     int evenIndex  = arr.length;
     for(int i=0; i < arr.length;i++) {
            if(arr[i] % 2 == 0 && evenIndex == arr.length) //even index
                evenIndex = i;

            else if( arr[i] % 2 != 0 ) {
                if(i > evenIndex ) {
                    shift (arr, evenIndex , i);
                    evenIndex ++;
                }
            }
     }
}

static void shift(int[] arr, int evenIndex, int endIndex) {
    int temp = arr[endIndex];
    for(int i = endIndex; i > evenIndex ;i --) {
        arr[i] = arr[i-1];
    }
    arr[evenIndex] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Yes, without much thinking it is solvable in a single scan, O(n), with roughly 1.5 extra space. But you will have to figure out how.

Comment: O(n) is possible. Single scan, maintain two lists/array one for even and one for odd. Append them in the end.

Comment: sorry about confusion, I was looking for in space solution

Comment: Look up information about "stable 0-1 sorting."

Comment: `in space (without using extra space)` the term you want to use is *(strictly) in-place* (O(1) additional space).

Answer (score 2):

Stable partition is what you are looking for

```
std::vector<int> l = {1, 4, 8, 3, 9, 12, 7};
std::stable_partition(l.begin(), l.end(),
                      [](int A) -> bool {
                          return (A & 1) == 1; // A is odd
                      });
```

[Exactly N applications of the predicate and O(N) swaps if there is enough extra memory. O(N log N) swaps and O(N) applications of the predicate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition)

[Question on how stable partition works along with its complexity.](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/which-algorithm-can-do-a-stable-in-place-binary-partition-with-only-on-moves)

A stable quick sort, for example, will use a stable partitioning under the hood. Check out the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71030397/stable-partition-in-c-why-is-it-on-lg-n) for an O(n*log(n)) implementation of a stable partition algorithm that is beautifully recursive.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify any language tag, so I'll answer using python (just because it's quicker for me to use it at the moment).

If you **only** care about space complexity you can do something like this:

```
l = [1, 4, 8, 3, 9, 12, 7]
even_index = -1

for index in range(0, len(l)):
    if (l[index] % 2) == 0:
        if even_index == -1:
            even_index = index
    else:
        if (index > 0) and (even_index > -1):
            num = l[index]
            l.insert(even_index, num)
            del l[index + 1]
            even_index += 1
print(l)
```

You keep an index of where the first even number is and insert the odd number as you find them going through the list. Then you remove the odd number at the "old" index (which is now increased by 1).

I think the space complexity is what you need, but the time complexity can be improved.

For example, in Python a `collections.deque` is probably better in this case, but time complexity was not a priority.

Comment: I suspect you became 'victim of the example' by coding your script to suit l = [1, 4, 8, 3, 9, 12, 7]. Change your l to [1,5, 4, 8, 3, 9, 12, 7] and you will find flaws with your solution.

Comment: Nah, I just forgot a check. But yes, there was a bug, now I edited it.

Comment: Going through your corrected code it appears to me that the time complexity is O(n^2) with insert and delete operations on list. Please correct me if I am wrong (Ref: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: @shal8mani You're probably correct because of the array but, as I said in the answer, time complexity was not considered in the question. Also, this is an example implementation. If you did the same with a doubly linked list, be it Python or C/C++, the time complexity would be O(n)

Comment: Sorry I missed that you answered only for space and not the time. Since its mentioned in the question that he's looking to improve time-complexity from O(n^2) I guessed your solutions takes care of that.

Comment: @shal8mani Actually no, he says `Can We improve this from O(n2) in space (without using extra space)?` . There is no mention of time complexity in the question.

Comment: Also I considered solving it through LinkedList but don't you think that'd take extra-space? I am not very sure of the implementation but I remember from C codes I used to write earlier I used to have another variable per structure storing pointer to the next node, so I guess it won't be space compliant. Would appreciate your feedback

Comment: I think he meant Can We improve this from O(n2), in space (without using extra space)?

Comment: If the OP only cares about space complexity, their original approach is already linear in space complexity, as yours is.