# stable partition in c++ - why is it O(n lg n)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++20

I was looking at the possible implementation of stable partition in c++: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/stable_partition

it’s stated this is at worst O nlgn.

How is this possible? it seems like in the worst case a rotate is called at every index, resulting in an O n**2 algorithm.

Comment: Regarding the example implementation it is explicitly mentioned that "This implementation does not use extra memory buffer and as such can be less efficient.", isn't it?

Comment: @ChristophFreundl the requirement is that implementations that do not use extra memory take `O(n log n)` operations. Those that do take extra memory ought to take `O(n)`.

Comment: There are implications of `stable_partition` that take no extra memory (except stack memory) and take `O(n lon n)` operations but indeed I don't see how the implementation in the example satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ALX23z notes, the sample implementation is not conforming with respect to running time. Here is what an O(n log n) in-place `stable_partition` could look like (at least from an algorithms perspective; if you want a library-grade implementation go look at the actual libraries).

```
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Iterator, typename Predicate>
Iterator my_stable_partition(Iterator first, Iterator last,
                             Predicate predicate) {
  auto n = std::distance(first, last);
  if (n <= 1) {
    if (n == 1 && predicate(*first))
      ++first;
    return first;
  }
  auto middle = first;
  std::advance(middle, n / 2);
  auto a = my_stable_partition(first, middle, predicate);
  auto b = my_stable_partition(middle, last, predicate);
  return std::rotate(a, middle, b);
}
```

Here's a quick and dirty test.

```
#include "my_stable_partition.cc"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

bool odd(int n) { return n % 2 == 0; }

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    std::vector<int> arr(i);
    long long checksum = 0;
    for (int &x : arr) {
      checksum += x = random() / 31337;
    }
    auto mid = my_stable_partition(arr.begin(), arr.end(), odd);
    for (auto it = arr.begin(); it != mid; ++it) {
      assert(odd(*it));
      checksum -= *it;
    }
    for (auto it = mid; it != arr.end(); ++it) {
      assert(!odd(*it));
      checksum -= *it;
    }
    assert(checksum == 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful recursive solution and uses std::lib functions. I had to think thru the recursion a bit. For example, assume you are partitioning based on odd numbers and after the final recursive call you have [1,3,5,2,4,7,9,6,8] where  [1,3,5,2,4] is the left half partitioned and [7,9,6,8] is the right half; We rotate the middle part [2,4,7,9] yielding [7,9,2,4] and end up with [1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8] -- which is correct!

Answer (score 0):

The above solution, as stated, does take O(log n) space on the stack.

I thought it might be possible to replace it with a true O(1) implementation, but that's really a non-starter because each recursive step returns a value, which is consumed by the rotate call that takes place afterwards.

So, even if you flattened the call tree into a single loop that knows what range to work on at each iteration...at best, you will need to keep O(log n) such "return values" *somewhere* (since any time you've calculated `a` but not `b` or vice versa, you need to store it somewhere until you can use both)

BTW, there is an academic paper which claims to solve this problem with O(n) time and O(1) space: [http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/~jyrki/Paper/KP1992bJ.pdf](http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/%7Ejyrki/Paper/KP1992bJ.pdf)

It's probably of no use whatsoever practically... the constants are pretty bad. Besides, you CAN probably spare O(log n) calls on the stack, and if not, log(n) counters on the heap, using the method I described earlier.